# Why both my gitlab and github repoes show a big difference result of git diff 2 branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I want to compare the difference of 2 branches, so I run `git diff --name-only v51 v5` and get the result

```
docs/custom protocol/bs.md
src/components/header-bar/index.vue
src/components/phone-bar/index.vue
src/constants/options.js
src/store/modules/callRecord.js
src/store/modules/callScreen.js
src/utils/request.js
src/views/call_record/index.vue
src/views/call_screen/components/CustomerEdit.vue
src/views/home/components/statistics.vue
src/views/home/index.vue
src/views/outcall_task/id.vue
```

Sourcetree gives me the same result too:
[image: sourcetree]

But to my surprise both gitlab and github gives me a totally different result!

My gitlab repo, which I set on the cloud, said 102 files are different

[image: gitlab]

My github repo said 44 files are different!

[image: github]

I double check I have pushed latest commit in v5 & v51 to gitlab & github repo.

```
bs-front ➤ git status                                                                               git:v51
On branch v51
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/v51'.

bs-front ➤ git checkout v5                                                                          git:v51
Switched to branch 'v5'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/v5'.
```

I don't understand why they both get a different result and they are both wrong!!!

The differences are those 12 files indeed.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have your own repo in three places: locally on PC, remote on GitHub, remote #2 on GitLab?

Comment: Exactly. I set up my own gitlab on the cloud

Comment: Can you describe how you push stuff around the three repositories? Local -> GitHub -> Gitlab? Local to both GitHub/GitLab? git push --mirror?

Comment: git push --all github & git push --all origin

Comment: You need to look at one of the files that differs between the three places and see if you understand why one is showing the difference but the others isn't.

Comment: are you the only one pushing to both? Do you ever fetch from both? If so, how?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I did look and I don't understand so I ask the question. It looks to me that both github & gitlab see these 2 branches' root differently and they are both wrong.

Comment: Are the same commits the tip of those branches across all locations?

Comment: Yes, see my git status result